# Dart polymer paper element - how to set attributes (dismissive and affirmative)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying this:

```dart
PaperButton pbOK = new PaperButton();
pbOK.innerHtml="OK";
pbOK.attributes={"affirmative":"xxxxx"};//wrong of course..??
```

which is Dart compiler-legal, but is incorrect.
What should it be please?

Answer (score 1):

```dart
pbOK.attributes["affirmative"] = "xxxxx"
```